# TextWatcher() in constant loop

Tags: android, textwatcher

Each time the user enters a letter it is stored in outData, then the TextView is cleared. Why is this in a constant loop? I thought the conditional statement would exit out of it but it keeps looping?

```
  writeText     = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.WriteText);

  writeText.addTextChangedListener(watch);

  TextWatcher watch = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

        if (writeText.getText() == "") {
            return;
        }
        else{
            String writeData = writeText.getText().toString();
            byte[] OutData = writeData.getBytes();
            ftDevice.write(OutData, writeData.length());
            writeText.setText("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int a, int b, int c) {

    }
};
```

Comment: Its going in loop because of writeText.setText(""); this statement.
These are delegate methods which are called when text is edited in edittexts. When you are programmatically calling writeText.setText(""); these methods will again be called

Comment: Why wont the if Statement work though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

1- Strings cannot be compared with == sign, there is an `equals` function for this, here you can simply check string length == 0 as base condition to return.

2- calling `setText()` would again trigger `TextWatcher` callbacks, instead edit the `Editable` object passed as argument and changes would get reflected.

Do it like this:

```
if (writeText.getText().length() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    else{
        String writeData = writeText.getText().toString();
        byte[] OutData = writeData.getBytes();
        ftDevice.write(OutData, writeData.length());
        arg0.replace(0, arg0.length(), "");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> String comparing use 'equals' method.
>
> String1.equals(String2) instead of ==.
>
> equals method is for comparing the contents and == is for comparing
>   the references and primitives ,not to the contents.